# при заполнении конкретной ячейки матрицы меняются и другие клетки

Tags: java, матрицы

Я создаю матрицу Inventory, и заполняю её объектами (предметами из игры), и когда я заполняю 1 ячейку инвентаря условным пистолетом, и меняю ему количество патронов на 12 всё ещё нормально, но когда я заполняю 2 ячейку, почему-то у пистолета в первой ячейке количество патронов становится таким-же, как и у 2. Такое-же изменения наблюдается, меняя название пистолета, или другие переменные пистолета.

```
    player.inventory[0][0] = itemsId.get(1);//заполнить инвентарь игрока предметом из таблицы
    player.inventory[0][0].weapon.ammo=1;
    System.out.println(player.inventory[0][0].weapon.ammo);
    player.inventory[2][0] = itemsId.get(1);//заполнить инвентарь игрока предметом из таблицы
    player.inventory[2][0].weapon.name="glock";
    player.inventory[2][0].weapon.ammo=3;
    System.out.println(player.inventory[0][0].weapon.ammo);
```

Этот кусочек кода выводит сначала 1, а потом 3, я прописал 2 раза в консоль 1 и ту же переменную.
itemsId.get(1) - это лист объектов, где 1 элемент - это пистолет.

Как это исправить? Чем это можно заменить?

Comment: На умы приходит только проблема со статикой. Случайно у вас нет статических классов? А так, все же, нужно больше информации

Comment: Я не использую статичные классы, но я даже понятия не имею откуда вылазит такой баг

Comment: Ссылка ведет на один и тот же объект, вы его каждый раз меняете

Comment: Я же сначала меняю объект по ссылке [0][0], а потом уже [2][0]

Comment: каким образом при назначении объекта в матрице с порядком [2][0] меняется и [0][0]

Comment: Я попробовал сделать это, создав ни к чему не привязанную новую матрицу, такой-же результат, может быть дело в классе, которым я заполняю матрицу, но я не понимаю, что не так с ним

Comment: Я попробую сделать копию проекта, и матрицу поменять на список списков, массив как-то странно работает с объектами класса

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже дал @Wonderf
Вы кладете в свою инвентарь в ячейку [0][0] и в ячейку [2][0] один и тот же объект, где бы вы его не поменяли, объект поменяется везде.

Comment: если хотите то положите в [2][0] новый объект копию первого, тогда у вас в разных ячейках будут лежать разные объекты.

Comment: а, понял, спасибо

Comment: я сделал копию через invectory[0][0] = new Slot(itemsId.get(1).getSlot()); - не работает

Comment: как мне сделать копию, без отсылки на оригинал?

Comment: ))
Создать новый объект используя new и вставить туда все значения из имеющегося объекта или просто вызвать у существующего объекта метод clone();

Comment: вот пример:
player.inventory[2][0] = itemsId.get(1).clone();

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, всё теперь работает

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю клон, создавая новый объект, и перенося туда все значения.

```
public Slot cloneItem (int id) {
    switch (itemsId.get(id).type) {
        case "weapon" -> {
            return new Slot(new Weapon(itemsId.get(id).weapon.image,itemsId.get(id).weapon.recoil,itemsId.get(id).weapon.spread,itemsId.get(id).weapon.rateOfFire,itemsId.get(id).weapon.bulletCount,itemsId.get(id).weapon.damage,itemsId.get(id).weapon.bulletSpeed,itemsId.get(id).weapon.bulletSpeedSpread,itemsId.get(id).weapon.countOfCartridges,itemsId.get(id).weapon.reloadDelay,itemsId.get(id).weapon.canZoom,itemsId.get(id).weapon.cartridgesType,itemsId.get(id).weapon.name));
        }
        case "boxOfCartridges" -> {
            return new Slot(new BoxOfCartridges(itemsId.get(id).boxOfCartridges.type,itemsId.get(id).boxOfCartridges.countOfCartridges,itemsId.get(id).boxOfCartridges.image));
        }
        default -> {
            return new Slot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Это и есть решение, я могу не правильно сформулировать ответ, я щас переформулирую